# Do objects need some time to know that the forces exerted on them are gone?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string, inertia

[image]

[image]

Okay, so I know how to solve this question, but I don't quite understand the concept behind it!

The solution simply states that the acceleration of m2 after the rope is cut will equal the force of tension divided by m2

But here's the deal.

hasn't the rope been cut?

So, the tension force will no longer be exerted on  m2.

And since no force is exerted on it, and there isn't friction either, it should move in state of inertia with acceleration that equals zero!

Why do we solve the question as if the force of tension still affects m2 even after the robe is cut.
does objects need some time to know the forces exerted on them are gone?
and if so, why?

Comment: Your free-body diagram for $m_2$ before the rope is cut is not complete... it's not just the tension.... What's the acceleration before the rope is cut?

Comment: Why do you assume there's no friction? Friction is necessary for the initial motion to have a constant speed, as specified in the problem.

Comment: @Chemomechanics because I'm not given the coefficient of friction, and it's not stated in the problem.

Comment: That's what I've been hinting at... as @Chemomechanics says... how else can you have zero acceleration before the rope is cut?

Comment: @Chemomechanics
I guess I know what you mean.
The force that will act on m2 after the rope is cut is the friction, and it's equal to the tension force and opposite in direction
I get it now!

Comment: I wish either if you could write that as an answer so I approve it!

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: It's allowed (and encouraged) to write your own answer, which would be good practice for understanding and explaining your solution. You already have good images for use in a clear and helpful answer; just add the additional necessary force and the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Since you have now come to realization that there must be friction,
let me leave you with one more thought.

There really is no formula for friction....

Friction is what it needs to be to satisfy Newton's Laws.
So, just because you aren't given a coefficient of friction,
it doesn't mean there is no friction.

(Similarly, the normal force is what it needs to be to satisfy Newton's Laws.)

---

OOPS... I misread the labels. I originally asked about $m_1$.
I really meant the mass on the horizontal track... $m_2$... now changed below.

Can you draw a free-body diagram of mass $m_2$?
Identify ALL of the objects applying a force on $m_2$.

Before the rope is cut, what is the acceleration?

Comment: I have edited the question and added F.B.D of both masses.
The problem states that the objects are moving with constant speed, so acceleration = Zero

Comment: @TalalSharaa I meant the free body diagram of $m_2$... now changed.

Comment: I edited it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance.